# How to /testfor snowball a snowball hitting the ground or mobs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I decided to make a snowball grenade, but I stuck at how to /testfor the snowball when it hits a mob or the ground. Is there a scoreboard command that can help me? For example

```
 /scoreboard players set @e[type=snowball] hit 1 {onground:1b}
```

Answer (score 1):

Constantly teleport an invisible entity to the snowball. Execute off of the invisible entity and test for the snowball. If it's not there, it's hit the ground.

Comment: Congratulations, among all currently existing 16 answers to the 11 "how to do something when a snowball hits" questions, this is actually the best one. All other ones are either straight up not working or outdated for many years.

Answer (score 0):

Or else use fire. Try something like /execute @[type=snowball] ~ ~ ~ /setblock ~ ~ ~ fire
And then test if the fire was placed or not with conditional or something along those lines. Idea from TheRedEngineer
Check this video:

Comment: This would also trigger when the snowball flies next to something or closely over something.